# Google Sign In not working in facebook in app browser

Tags: facebook, inappbrowser, google-signin

We have a website with "Login with Google" feature. It works fine in chrome. However, when I share the link on Facebook, Facebook opens it in In-App browser and "Login with Google" doesn't work there.

I checked Stack Overflow's login with google functionality in facebook's In-App browser and it was working fine. Can anyone help me here? What are we missing?

Our website:
[solutions.acharyaprashant.org](https://solutions.acharyaprashant.org)
[books.acharyaprashant.org](https://books.acharyaprashant.org)

Comment: Same issue.  I believe that only works with redirect mode (ux_mode: 'redirect'). I have seen others applications, like etoro, that it has google signin in mobile web, but not in facebook in app. It surprises me that in twitter it works perfectly.

Comment: I love Facebook, really...

Answer (score 0):

This is Facebook In-App Browser
You can code js:

```
<script>

var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

function isFacebookApp() {
    return (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1);

}

if (isFacebookApp()) {
  if (!window.location.href.match('redirect_fb')) {
    // force open in browser ... 
  }
}

</script>
```